# Повторение цикла foreach с определенным шагом.

Tags: php, foreach

Здравствуйте.

Есть конструкция:

```
$start = 0;
$end = 10;
foreach($names as $name) if($start++ <= $end) {
}
```

Необходимо повторять цикл от 0 до 300 раз. Каждый раз цикл должен проходить 10 итераций, затем еще 10 и т.д.
т.е. от 0 до 10-ти, затем от 10-ти до 20, от 20 до 30-ти... и так до 300.

**Вопрос:** как реализовать цикл с шагом, например, в 10 итераций?

Comment: @DeN_, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

[array_chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) вам в помощь.

```
$groups = array_chunk($names, 10);
foreach($groups as $group) {
    foreach($group as $name) {
        //....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Такой вариант не подойдет?

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= 300; $i += 10) {
$name = $names[$i];
...
}
```